# LESS hide first element with class in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

I'm currently trying to hide a button using LESS. My HTML looks the following way:

```
<div class="targets">
   <div class="target">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn-delete" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem: I use jQuery to add a "target" div to "targets" div, the html looks like this after the DOM manipulation:

```
<div class="targets">
   <div class="target">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn-delete" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="target">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn-delete" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="target">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn-delete" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I always want to **hide the first button** with the class btn-delete. I use LESS.

My current LESS looks like this:

```
.targets {
    button[type="button"] {
        .btn-delete {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately my LESS coding doesn't work as I expected.

Do you know how to solve this issue, thus to always hide the first .btn-delete button with LESS Css?

Thanks! :)

Comment: think it should be `button[type="button"].btn-delete {` because your code say that you have a button that has a child with the class `btn-delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello use below code it work properly

```
.targets{
    .target:first-child{  
       button[type="button"] {
        &.btn-delete{ 
          visibility: hidden;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: cool thanks, I just made a plunk to try it out: https://plnkr.co/edit/KeqHZBKjHG6VIosOZo9h?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

As you are targeting the button with `btn-delete` class, You need `&` operator

```
.targets {
    button[type="button"] {
        &.btn-delete {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

*OR*, Traditional way

```
.targets {
    button[type="button"].btn-delete {
            visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its applying the visibility to a element with a class inside the button so

```
.targets {
  button[type="button"].btn-delete {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Would look for button[type="button"] with the class .btn-delete.